# How to define the correct Bundler version? (Capistrano deployment problem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, bundler

I'm currently trying to deploy my Rails application with Capistrano. I don't get any errors when I `cap deploy` but when I open the browser I see: "Your Gemfile.lock was generated by Bundler 0.10. You must delete it if you wish to use Bundler 0.9. (Bundler::GemfileError)"

I installed bundler on both machines, my local machine and the production box. I assume the latter uses a system wide gem that is of a different version. How do I define which version is the right one?

Some background:

Apache/Passenger, Rails 3.0.3, Capistrano 2.6.0, Bundler 1.0.15. The binary of the manually installed gem is found in `/var/www/htdocs/web18/.gems/bin/bundle`. I also added the following lines to my `config/deploy.rb`:

```
set :default_environment, {
  'GEM_HOME'    => '/var/www/htdocs/web18/.gems',
  'GEM_PATH'    => '/var/www/htdocs/web18/.gems',
  'BUNDLE_PATH' => '/var/www/htdocs/web18/.gems'
}

set :bundle_cmd, '/var/www/htdocs/web18/.gems/bin/bundle'
```

After deployment I see all Gems in `/var/www/htdocs/web18/.gems/gems/`

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Consider deleting the `Gemfile.lock` and running `bundle` again to see if this works.  Also, you should try to use RVM as well as being able to setup gemsets is a life saver at times like these.

If the above doesn't work do `gem list` and uninstall the older version of bundler if you find more than one on your system.

Comment: Thanks Mike, for your suggestions. However deleting the `Gemfile.lock` has no effect. It installs all gems like before but at the end I see the same error which tells me that the `Gemfile.lock` was generated by Bundler 0.10. I don't think there's a problem with the deployment. It's the app that uses the wrong Bundler version. Unfortunately I'm not able to uninstall it since it's a shared host. Maybe it's time to contact the support.